# Square of Pauli-Lubanski operator

Tags: special-relativity, lie-algebra, poincare-symmetry, invariants

I am following Ashok Das QFT [book](http://gr.xjtu.edu.cn/c/document_library/get_file?p_l_id=21699&folderId=2383653&name=DLFE-82650.pdf) (pg. 152-153) on the calculation of the Pauli Lubanski operator.

The Pauli Lubanski vector operator is defined as $$W^\mu=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\rho}P_\nu M_{\lambda\rho}$$
where $P_\nu$ and $M_{\lambda\rho}$ are the generators of Poincare transformations given by $P_\nu=\partial_\nu$ and $M_{\lambda\rho}=x_\lambda\partial_\rho-x_\rho \partial_\lambda$.

In equation 4.98 the author calculated the square of the Pauli Lubanski operator to be
$$W^2=W^\mu W_\mu=-\frac{1}{2}M^{\lambda\rho}M_{\lambda\rho}P^2-M_{\lambda\rho}M^{\nu\lambda}P_\nu P^\rho.\tag{4.98}$$

One of the intermediate steps confuses me:
$$W^2=-\frac{1}{2}M_{\lambda\rho}P_\nu M^{\lambda\rho} P^\nu - \frac{1}{4}M_{\lambda\rho}P_\nu M^{\nu\lambda} P^\rho + \frac{1}{4} M_{\lambda\rho}P_{\nu} M^{\nu\rho} P^\lambda -\frac{1}{4} M_{\lambda\rho}P_\nu M^{\rho\nu} P^\lambda  + \frac{1}{4} M_{\lambda\rho}P_\nu M^{\lambda\nu} P^\rho = -\frac{1}{2}M_{\lambda\rho}P_\nu M^{\lambda\rho} P^\nu -M_{\lambda\rho}P_\nu M^{\nu\lambda} P^\rho$$

I tried this myself and used the fact that $M^{\mu\nu}=-M^{\nu\mu}$ and got

$$W^2=-\frac{1}{2} M_{\lambda\rho}P_\nu M^{\lambda\rho}P^\nu -\frac{1}{2}M_{\lambda\rho}P_\nu M^{\nu\lambda} P^\rho -\frac{1}{2}M_{\lambda\rho}P_\nu M^{\rho\nu}P^\lambda$$

How do I proceed further to get what the author got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there: it should be clear that the first term of your expression is just

$$-\frac{1}{2} M_{\lambda\rho}P_\nu M^{\lambda\rho}P^\nu = -\frac{1}{2} M_{\lambda\rho} M^{\lambda\rho}P^2,$$ since $P_\nu P^\nu \equiv P^2$. Furthermore, it's possible to show (by manipulating indices) that $$\frac{1}{2}M_{\lambda\rho}P_\nu M^{\nu\lambda} P^\rho = \frac{1}{2}M_{\lambda\rho}P_\nu M^{\rho\nu}P^\lambda \label{star}\tag{$1$}$$

We can do this quite trivially by taking the right-hand side and redefining the indices $\rho\leftrightarrow\lambda$. These are dummy indices being summed over, so this is allowed. Note, however, that this is **not** the same as flipping the *order* of the indices; I am just choosing to call $\rho$ what I used to call $\lambda$ and vice-versa everywhere in the RHS. However, once this is done, I can *then* flip the order of the indices of $M$ and make use of its anti-symmetry. Therefore

\begin{aligned}\text{R.H.S of (\ref{star}) = }\frac{1}{2}M_{\lambda\rho}P_\nu M^{\rho\nu}P^\lambda &= \frac{1}{2}M_{\rho\lambda}P_\nu M^{\lambda\nu}P^\rho \quad \quad \text{Redefining $\rho\leftrightarrow\lambda$}\\ &=\frac{1}{2}M_{\lambda\rho}P_\nu M^{\nu\lambda}P^\rho \quad \quad \text{Using $M_{\alpha\beta} = -M_{\beta\alpha}$}\\~\\ &=\text{L.H.S of  (\ref{star})} \end{aligned}

Using this, it should be clear why:

$$W^2=-\frac{1}{2} M_{\lambda\rho} M^{\lambda\rho}P^2 - M_{\lambda\rho} M^{\nu\lambda} P_\nu P^\rho$$